# Delete cells in range if less than current date

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a range of dates in plain text format (must stay this way) and I need to clear them at 1am if the date in each range cell is less than the current date. I can set up the run schedule later, but can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

I'm using =TEXT(TODAY(),"m/dd") to insert the current date in the correct format in cell AE3.

Thank you!

```
function clearOldDate() 
{

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Loads");
    var cells = sheet.getRange('AC9:AE33').getValues();
    var data = [cells];

    var date = sheet.getRange('AE3').getValues();
    //var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0900','MM/dd');



    for(i=0; i<76; i++) 
    {


          if (date > data[i])
          {
              data[i].clear();  
          };
    };
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
function clearOldDate() 
{

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("LogSheet");
    //getValues gives a 2D array. 
    var data = sheet.getRange('AC9:AE33').getValues();

    var date = sheet.getRange('AE3').getValues();
    //var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0900','MM/dd');


    //This for loop with loop through each row
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
    {
          //This for loop with loop through each column
         for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length ; j ++){
          //This assumes Column AC has the dates you are comparing aganist
          if (date > data[i][j])
           {   
              //sets that the Row with index i to empty
              data[i] =  ["","",""]
           };
          }
    };
     //finally set the value back into sheet
     sheet.getRange('AC9:AE33').setValues(data)
     };
```

Basically, you need to setValues once data array is modified.

**Note:** This Statement (date > data[i][0]) doesn't work as expected when the values are stored as text.

**Edit:** Modified the code and added a new for loop to go through each column, based on comments

Comment: This does clear dates in AC but it doesn't fully work for my purposes because an old date may be in any column. AC,AD,orAE. Each cell in AC9:AE33 needs to be considered separately.

Comment: You can fix that by adding an another for loop within the first one to increment in each column.

Comment: I updated the code, should work the way you intend it to

Comment: Thanks Jagannathan! I had to change  data[i] =  ["","",""]  to data[i][j] =  [""]; for it to only delete old dates in each cell instead of the whole row but very helpful!!!

Comment: Now any ideas on how I can increase the date by 1 day with this code?

Comment: Since your date is stored as text your can use dateElem = date.split('/') to get an array of two elements. dateElem[0] will have the month and dateElem[1] will have your date. Just added one to dateElem[1] = Number(dateElem[1]) + 1. Join the arrays to get a new date like so newDate = dateElem.join('/'). However you will have keep track of when date goes over 28/30/31 based on the month

Comment: Also if you need further help or suggestion with "increasing the date by 1" please open a new thread. That way more people can help you with it, questions in comments reduce the visibility of your question. Thanks!

Comment: So do I need to insert a 3rd for loop to split the date into the two parts?

Comment: Thanks, For all your help!